# Accuracy Beyond Current Rating of Current Transformer

Tags: transformer, maximum-ratings

We're currently working with a current transformer of the follow specifications:
[image]

Link:http://www.eastrongroup.com/productsview/30.html
I'm a bit confused when it says it's still accurate up to 120%. Does that mean it's able to output beyond 333 mV (near 400 mV)?

Also, are these ratings in RMS or Peak?

Edit: Changed "beyond 120%" to "up to 120%"

Comment: Where does it say it's accurate to beyond 120%? I can only see accuracy rated over the 20 to 120% range.

Comment: Apologies, I meant "Up to 120%." I'll edit it. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to dispute veracity of the data.  I will use the 600A model on an induction motor to quantify my answer.

> I'm a bit confused when it says it's still accurate beyond 120%. Does that mean it's able to output beyond 333 mV (near 400 mV)?

It says 20% to 120%.

- 120A = 66.6mV
- 600A = 333mV = Rated full-load current
- 720A = 399.6mV

So Current Transformer output can go beyond 333 mV.  These voltages are to allow an appropriate meter or D/A conversion.

The current on a motor can exceed rated full-load current, so the measuring equipment must be able to reflect this.  The locked rotor or starting current on induction motors can be 5 to 8 times full-load current, but this would be for a short time < 1-3 seconds.  So output will go beyond 400mV.

The 100%-120% allows long time over full-load current detection, which will not activate circuit protection devices.  A fuse typically burns at 120% of full-load current, but any current above full-load current creates heat in motor windings which could impact motor life.

Comment: Apologies, I mistyped. I meant "up to 120%."

Comment: Thank you, I learned that these current transformers are rated this way because of induction motors. I didn't know they come hand in hand, in a way.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a picture of the front page to the device (does anything look or feel familiar?)

[image]

I have concerns about this device. Clearly, with a company name of Eastron they are making some attempt to hi-jack the reputable Eaton name (who also make split-core current transformers): -

[image]

Additionally, the specifications (accuracy and phase angle error) make the Zhejiang/China device a poor choice for accurate power measurements. So, I would recommend that you do a lot of digging and research into what it is you actually need and, find a component from Eaton that appears to suit and make technical comparisons with an equivalent one made in China.

I'm not pointing a jingoistic finger at Eastron in China other than to say that anyone partially copying the name of a US based reputable supplier of the same goods have some agenda that is worth investigating.

> *I'm a bit confused when it says it's still accurate beyond 120%. Does
>   that mean it's able to output beyond 333 mV (near 400 mV)?*

You have to be suspicious about any company that is trying to muscle in on another company's good name.

> *Also, are these ratings in RMS or Peak?*

Ignoring the doubts I have about the China company and their motives, the default values for any AC measurement in the power field is RMS.

Comment: in the middle of your great answer you misspelled Eaton as Easton.  Also, thanks for teaching me a new word.  :-)

Comment: @relayman357 was that new word jingoistic? Fixing the misspell.

Comment: Yes, thanks Andy.

Comment: Oh boy. Thank you for pointing this out. Since our boss bought these already (without our consultation), I'll subject these to my own testing to see if the specifications hold up.